Using php wordwrap function to split a string into array for GD image processing
Please I am trying to write a function that will enable me split long text in a textarea into multi lines using something similar to php wordwrap function. How ever I need the result in foreach arrays so i can bind the result to my GD Image code so that long text area broken line my line.
Below is the echo wordwrap function I use to break the text into lines. How ever now I would love to explode the string based on php wordwrap into arrays. Thank you
<?php
$str = 'Long Text with line breaks, line 1, Line 2, Line 3' ; 
        echo wordwrap($str,25,"<br>\n");  
?>
 

I am trying to achieve the following below
Array
(
    [0] => Long Text with line breaks
    [1] => Line 1
    [2] => Line 2
    [3] => Line 3

)


Can't you use explode?

@shingo well i could use explode but i would want to split based on 25 characters and wouldn't want complete words broken in different lines.
It seems wordwarp can get this done. I may be wrong though ......

What does it mean? "Long Text with line breaks" is longer than 25 characters, "Line1", "Line2" and "Line3" are all shorter than 25 characters. You may add some examples to explain why you can't use explode.

@shingo Oh what i mean is this
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Line one -> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Line two - > consectetur adipiscing elit
And so on.  (Character limit 25 but shouldn't break words apart)

And what should the line three be like?

@shingo its just a foreach loop of arrays based on the text length of the string. I just used that as an example.

Use some character sequence that will never occur in your actual input text as the wordwrap $break string - and then explode the result at that sequence.
